# kotlin Pass multiple values on CheckChanged using databinding

Tags: kotlin, data-binding

In Kotlin checkbox from XML databinding I want to pass 3 arguments checked or not (Boolean) and Two Strings.

Currently I am passing as below

```
 android:onCheckedChanged="@{(switch, checked) -> availMasterVm.onCheckedChangedMondayMrng(checked)}"
```

when I add String I am getting error how to pass strings to the viewmodel method

Comment: Which strings do you want to pass here?

Comment: to this method onCheckedChangedMondayMrng(checked, "Monday", "Morning")

Comment: You always want to pass "Monday" and "Morning"? Probably not. What is the source of these strings?

Comment: I am having multiple check boxes so each checkbox having different significance we can say the strings passed for each checkbox is different and indicates purpose of that checkbox, so I want to pass two strings along with checked.

Comment: `onCheckedChangedMondayMrng` this same function is called by all checkboxes?

Comment: yes the same method but strings values will change statically

Comment: Hi any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the extra parameters in just the usual way. Just remember that for strings you need to use back-ticks(``) instead of double quotes("").

```kotlin
 android:onCheckedChanged="@{(switch, checked) -> availMasterVm.onCheckedChangedMondayMrng(checked, `Monday`, `Morning`)}"
```

Comment: Did this work ?

Comment: Yes just added ` and able to pass strings